# Typescript - map an array of objects of different types using discriminated union

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is the scenario:

I have an array of objects that I am using to define inputs fields that get rendered in a react app. Objects contain all the props required by each field type. To handle different types of fields I have created a component for each one, along with its own typing. Each object has a prop `fieldType` that defines which component will be rendered.

I have defined the array of objects using a discriminated union of all the input field types (using `fieldType`).

```
// The types for each of my inputs
type InputText = {
    fieldType: 'text';
    id: string;
    label: string;
    value: string;
    onChange: (value: string, id: string) => void;
    // ... other props
}
type InputNumeric = {
    fieldType: 'numeric';
    id: string;
    label: string;
    value: string;
    onChange: (value: string, id: string) => void;
    // ... other props
}
type InputSelect = {
    fieldType: 'select';
    id: string;
    label: string;
    value: string;
    onChange: (value: string, id: string) => void;
    // ... other props
}

// The union of all my inputs
type InputTypes = InputText | InputNumeric | InputSelect
```

Now when I create the array of objects everything works if I explicitly define the relevant props on each object.

```
type ValuesType = {
    name: string;
    age: string;
}

const [values, seValues] = useState<ValuesType>({
    name: '',
    age: ''
})

const handleChange = useCallback((value: string, id: string) => {
    setValues({...values, [id as keyof ValuesType]: value })
}, [values])

/* THIS WORKS */
const fields:InputTypes[] = [
    {
        fieldType: 'text',
        id: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
        value: values['name'],
        onChange: handleChange
    },
    {
        fieldType: 'numeric',
        id: 'age',
        label: 'age',
        value: values['age'],
        onChange: handleChange
    }
]
```

However, I want to store and retrieve my field definitions. So, I have to apply the `value` and `onChange` props by using `.map` on my array of objects once I have retrieved them. Also seems silly to type out exactly the same thing for every object.

```
const fields:InputTypes[] = [
    {
        fieldType: 'text',
        id: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
    },
    {
        fieldType: 'numeric',
        id: 'age',
        label: 'age',
    }
].map(f => ({
    ...f,
    value: values[f.id as keyof ValuesType],
    onChange: handleChange
}))
```

But when I do this Typescript complains.

```
Type '{ value: any; onChange: any; fieldType: string; id: string; label: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'InputTypes[]'.
  Type '{ value: any; onChange: any; fieldType: string; id: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'InputTypes'.
    Type '{ value: any; onChange: any; fieldType: string; id: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'InputSelect'.
      Types of property 'fieldType' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"select"'.
```

The code works as intended but I cannot for the life of me get my typings right. Where am I going wrong? How are they different? I have created a [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAwjgDbkBGOAxgNZwC+cAZlBCHAORTp0xuAWABQogPTi4AFQAW6ODACeYdKjbQ4-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-CUTyIVMkjgHB1HodAlH0OBCLfVR00iL1mDAw4yJPdMOMncQACoZAACXsTA4AAdQAeQAJQAaTE-jxBLOAIKg3VgijAcOwze5U2U3Iv2WXIdRefV3iiXt-304zfHNT413QKyRCMmy8gKG1uHOBynJcmzEwdK9UFTezrm4dMAOcqRXOReDt2gjpYPQWL0Gs3wmAi3yHkyky9WpD5yR+P4Mqi1y7KAnySps2MPnK4rooC+ET2C8rwtS4zXVROKYLgzqUsi4z5WWTMpwE4TRLgAARSSAFExPOSTpAkmTZLgRTwMPfw9U0s5tJvLw9PtPDXPUsyaWiQQIuiuyf0cy7XOqngvNCu60pe7VjtMvKeAK24nKuoFuFqgFcgewGPT+vx5XTFYQBwMAugMIlPwBCVWDe-ymtYFYKKouAaLogxGOpVqXRRd0am6pLet3MYxiAA) to demonstrate

Thank you in advance. I am only just adopting Typescript into my projects so greatly appreciate helping me understand.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsFNQFwJ4AdoGdQDMD2AnU0BDAY0lCw1AFsFQBLAOyQFc5UBYAKERVAElGW4aAA84oALygA3p1BzMtaABsAJuGTQAXKADkcEXB0BuWfNortqODgYBzEx3mglBAEbLL1uw6cA3AkpMWqBWNvT2pnJY9ADCkAThwQAU-oHBoXYANHQWIV7hAJQSAHygvljmPvIgoAB09WRwMHhIOFhI7BwAvpzcsPzMcAByTJTQNkQS0pEKymoa2jr0o%20O0RMYz5p5hEY7yLu5K294zqUHH4VVRsfGJ2ikB53k72VvPdkXipeWVM8uU7hwADFcJQCHBFkQmDgcNB6EQEDpQAAfXQoHBEOFwAi2aBI1FLUaAnQzGr1WqNZqgVrtTo9LgaPgCOAAZWU0CIYkkMj2cgwilU6hQi1Q7M5G15OQuuycBw870up0e6XyMvk0TiCVx9zOKpeUoVtk%203wqKiuoDJDSwTXG1LaHU49M4NSgsCY9Fo0TIFACSioNAYg06fSZgyFaCmA0EBhRoZYIzGE1jUdZYrgnAzDJ4ADVlahw1MeU56AQxtLzTi9SdupmiNErKAANq61DZUW5tKoAC6UyYopZ2P0AB4O0F8xpikki-IS2XdDpMjNK4sSd0CrX62JbiolNBNYle6KYr7XMQANZJB5paWvXIZQolaaS0VwUdoKd1eot7KN8ygAjoGe0AIOQoBvuOKBdtouqgF067dD%20LZdvBmbAAAVBAAASvAsqAADqADyABKADSuFocAzpgHW9ANvycyoJoKbhqgjY9pIjZUU4T41Nx8j0YKCy6PoogLlxfFyG8Sylnii4cLxElykcuhDDJYnyWAEllMq0F5o20ljDoXZyQpfEarc2qgNuu77ri4nyF0JmafIPKmdxAnzMKuj-Ks6xOVpBo6JW6lubKbjykFuIhc5fG6rpnb6cFxn2WZNxasE1l7hZ0ApbBXFdhutFiAw%20g4JQtBwPo9AQgR5VwEOzEaK2oAAES6i1sYteZ6UtcUbFTJxkrTnxHnhosImGHJWlSbOskzGFhyLKphlTQ5q1yMN7kCp5wSEomazqdNuSRXNkoLRFwXrdx-yAiCZXgosN3jKuTj0gVHCcDRdHbYxcZwCx-WSCV4x1VVcC1GCSBJBQXygFOMzkhgV1xdpCUYLUf4AaAQEgRQ4HhslkrdXcVkJDuWXpY6BQofJGHgNhuEACIEQAorhQwEeA%20HESRoAUah1GbrMqiMY1KCsexTa5a5MVbXMY3CQY0UBTNan%20VpSlLWruWOdLuVOKNQl7b5ytHYsl36-s4XKSdpsOflEMEFDMOlPDGncYj6vyCjLaNujmOAcBoH4xohNucTlmZbZOXu3BBRAA) for question on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75774412/12033293)

Comment: Your playground has errors in `useState` and other react stuff.  If you need that to ask the question, could you [edit] the playground to import whatever you need?  If you don't need it, then could you [edit] the code and the playground to remove references to it (and I guess remove react tags)? Also it would help if your discriminated union example actually differed by more than just the discriminant, otherwise you don't need a union at all (just have a single object type whose `fieldType` property is a union).

Comment: Thank you @jcalz. Sorry I didn't realise I could do things like import from libraries. I have updated. I included them so that you could see what I was trying to map to the fields. And sorry I was trying to keep the example to a minimum and left the fact that the types are different to be implicit in my question. But I have added more values in to make it explicit. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an intermittent variable by omitting the value and onChange fields.

```js
const intermittent:Omit<InputTypes, "value" | "onChange">[] = [
    {
        fieldType: 'text',
        id: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
    },
    {
        fieldType: 'numeric',
        id: 'age',
        label: 'age',
    }
]

const fields: InputTypes[] = intermittent.map(f => ({
    ...f,
    value: values[f.id as keyof ValuesType],
    onChange: handleChange
}))
```

Or you can put as const to every object, to tell typescript that their fieldTypes are not just string.

```js
const fields:InputTypes[] = [
    {
        fieldType: 'text',
        id: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
    } as const,
    {
        fieldType: 'numeric',
        id: 'age',
        label: 'age',
    } as const
].map(f => ({
    ...f,
    value: values[f.id as keyof ValuesType],
    onChange: handleChange
}))
```

**Update**:

This sort of structure both works and reads well too, I think.

```js
// Without common fields
type InputText = {
    fieldType: 'text';
    id: string;
    label: string;
}
....

type BaseTypes = InputText | InputNumeric | InputSelect
type Common = {value: string, onChange: (value: string, id: string) => void}
type InputTypes = BaseTypes & Common

const intermittent: BaseTypes[] = [
    {
        fieldType: 'text',
        id: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
    },
    {
        fieldType: 'numeric',
        id: 'age',
        label: 'age',
        numberFormat: 'number'
    }
]

const fields: InputTypes[] = intermittent.map(f => ({
    ...f,
    value: values[f.id as keyof ValuesType],
    onChange: handleChange
}))
```

Comment: thank you so much. I tried out your answers, the const option worked, but I am not sure if that would work if I am pulling a JSON object then mapping it? I liked the look of the first option but it fails once I include other props, it only seems to accept props that are common to all. I have done another playground - was too long for the comment so I will an add edit to my question.

Comment: [Do you mean "intermediate" instead of "intermittent"](https://wikidiff.com/intermediate/intermittent)?

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't create the components without the common fields as they needed to be standalone components still (inputs that could be used anywhere) but I just stripped them by using `type Stripped<T> = Omit<T, 'value' | 'onChange'>` and my base props `type BaseFields = Stripped<InputTextProps> | Stripped<InputNumericProps> | Stripped<InputSelectProps>`